# Spring security only allowed oauth login

Tags: spring, oauth

In my project, i just want to allow oauth login. my spring security config as follow:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login.html", "/oauth/**", "/sign**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()[enter image description here][1]
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login.html")
        .and()
            .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
}
```

The problem is the access denied page not working. I want to get login.html content as follow:
[login.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gbj4.png)

in fact i got 403 page as follow:
[403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzpeA.png)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem, the code as follow:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.html", "/oauth/**", "/sign**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new HttpForbiddenEntryPoint(), AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout.html")
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html")
        .and()
            .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());

}
```

The entry point:

```
public class HttpForbiddenEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private String redirect_url = "/login.html";

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.sendRedirect(redirect_url);

    }

    public String getRedirect_url() {
        return redirect_url;
    }

    public void setRedirect_url(String redirect_url) {
        this.redirect_url = redirect_url;
    }
}
```